# Angular: Mat Sort not working for table like expansion

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular9

I am trying to sort the table but it's not getting sort. I have found the problem for not happening. It's not happening because `mat-sort-header` is not matching with the model. But the problem is my JSON object is not the same as this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-like-mat-accordion?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Also for the name part, my data is coming from `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName` and I have to show it as Name only. Let me show my JSON object and my HTML below:

**JSON object received from API**

```
[
    {
        "exam": {
            "examCategory": {
                "examCategoryName": "Freshers",
                "id": 157,
                "timestamp": "2020-07-07 11:55:22.425"
            },
            "examName": "First Demo",
            "timestamp": "2020-07-07 15:17:32.0"
        },
        "id": 94,
        "user": {
            "id": 9,
            "firstName": "AVISHEK",
            "middleName": "DATTA",
            "lastName": "RAY",
            "timestamp": "2020-07-07 15:06:58.186"
        },
        "timestamp": "2020-07-07 13:15:24.898"
    }
]
```

**example.component.html**

```
isplayMode="flat" class="mat-table" [class.d-none]="isLoading || length==0">
  <section matSort class="mat-elevation-z2 mat-header-row">
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="user.id">User Id</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="name">Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examName">Exam Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examCategoryName">Exam Category</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="marks">Marks Obtained</span>
  </section>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let result of selectedResult | async">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="mat-row">
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.user.id }}</span>
      <span class="mat-cell">
        {{ result.user.firstName | titlecase }} 
        {{ result.user.middleName | titlecase }} 
        {{ result.user.lastName | titlecase }}
      </span>
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.exam.examName }}</span>
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.exam.examCategory.examCategoryName }}</span>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="row">
      // Any Body //
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

As in TS I have declared `selectedResult`  as `selectedResult : Observable<any[]>` I have given `mat-sort-header` names on my own.
What change do I need to make the sorting work?

Comment: You should also share your `example.component.ts` code.

Comment: Create a stackblitz example with complete code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.. but you can try like this...

**When you received JSON object from API**

In **`example.component.ts`**

```
undortedData: any;
mainData: any;
this.mainData = [
 {
    "exam": {
        "examCategory": {
            "examCategoryName": "Freshers",
            "id": 157,
            "timestamp": "2020-07-07 11:55:22.425"
        },
        "examName": "First Demo",
        "timestamp": "2020-07-07 15:17:32.0"
    },
    "id": 94,
    "user": {
        "id": 9,
        "firstName": "AVISHEK",
        "middleName": "DATTA",
        "lastName": "RAY",
        "timestamp": "2020-07-07 15:06:58.186"
    },
    "timestamp": "2020-07-07 13:15:24.898"
 }
];

this.undortedData = [...this.mainData];

    sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.unsortedData.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.mainData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.mainData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'name': return this.compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    })

  }

    compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
       return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
      }
```

**In your `example.component.html`**

```
</mat-accordion> isplayMode="flat" class="mat-table" [class.d-none]="isLoading || length==0">
  <section matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" class="mat-elevation-z2 mat-header-row">
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="user.id">User Id</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="name">Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examName">Exam Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examCategoryName">Exam Category</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="marks">Marks Obtained</span>
  </section>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let result of selectedResult | async">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="mat-row">
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.user.id }}</span>
      <span class="mat-cell">
        {{ result.user.firstName | titlecase }} 
        {{ result.user.middleName | titlecase }} 
        {{ result.user.lastName | titlecase }}
      </span>
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.exam.examName }}</span>
      <span class="mat-cell">{{ result.exam.examCategory.examCategoryName }}</span>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="row">
      // Any Body //
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: in ```mat-sort-header``` can we write heading name as ```user.id``` because whenever am writing like this it's not sorting but writing only ```id``` does

Comment: @Avishek so, I think you should write `id` .

Comment: OR you can use `table` instead you use `section` .. Because I have used this `matSort` in `table` and it's working perfectly.

Comment: ya for table I know it's easy but my requirement is expansion  panel

Comment: I just now tried this with mat-table but what am seeing is that the ```Name```  column is not sorting

Comment: @Avishek and other **columns are sorting** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <section matSort class="mat-elevation-z2 mat-header-ro (matSortChange)="sortData($event)>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="user.id">User Id</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="name">Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examName">Exam Name</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="examCategoryName">Exam Category</span>
    <span class="mat-header-cell" mat-sort-header="marks">Marks Obtained</span>
  </section>

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.yourJsonData.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }
```

Like this you have to set **matSortChange** Event in to your section. it should work after apply this

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the `sortData(sort: Sort)` code given in [sort header angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples) documentation given according to the structure of your data.

1. Change the `mat-sort-header="user.id"` to `mat-sort-header="userId"`. The text will be needed only to match cases in your `sortData(sort: Sort)`, hence doesn't have to be dotted notation. Also, I'm not sure if it will work with dotted notation.
2. Modify the inputs to the compare function in the switch cases. Like for **examName** pass on `compare(a.exam.examName, b.exam.examName, isAsc)` i.e in accordance to your JSON data structure.
3. Getting the name row sorted is a bit tricky for **name** thing. In html you are using string interpolation to display the concatenated names, similarly use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to pass concatenated names to the subsequent compare function.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrqpsh) for your understanding.

Note:- Haven't added the marks part since the api response doesn't have any marksObtained property, but I'm guessing it's a number, just pass along similar to the ***userid***.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that your JSON is not correct and let's assume you have corrected it for yourself as of now.
Also, it looks like you want an expandable row(not really `mat-expansion-panel`) with matSort functionality

Use
Table with expandable rows [link](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)